# lme4 convergence warning in specific subset of data

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, convergence

Our main analysis consists of univariate logistic mixed models using `lme4`’s `glmer` to check for an association between plasma biochemical parameters (which are used in the model below as scaled continuous variables) and disease outcome in a dataset of N~4000.

As a form of sensitivity analysis, we remove participants using supplements to see how our results change (reducing the dataset by approximately one-third, i.e., N~2600).

The main model:

`Disease ~ age + sex + BMI + biochemical_parameter + (1|Family_group)`

where age & BMI are continuous covariates, runs fine & without any warnings for any of the biochemical parameters.

The model in the sensitivity analysis (the same formula but now only using patients who take no supplements) throws the following warnings for most of the biochemical parameters:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues
3: In vcov.merMod(full, useScale = FALSE) :
  variance-covariance matrix computed from finite-difference Hessian is
not positive definite or contains NA values: falling back to var-cov estimated from RX
4. In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
```

(The warnings change depending on which biochemical parameter is used).

The warnings cannot be ignored since the results I get are not credible (enormous odds ratios; huge SE; many p-values = 1, even when confidence intervals or the odds ratio do not contain 1).

I’ve read through the [help pages](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html) for these warnings and many CV posts on these warnings but still cannot find a solution. What I’ve tried so far:

- Various optimisers
- Rescaling continuous parameters (and even after doing this, the warning that ends in `Rescale variables?` remains)
- Lowered the tolerance (optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5))
- Restarted fit from previous fit

Other potentially helpful clues I’ve found from troubleshooting:

- I never get the warnings on the null model, which does not include the biochemical_parameter (i.e.,  `Disease ~ age + sex + BMI + (1|Family_group)`)
- I get the warnings less frequently when I run the model with the biochemical parameter but without age or BMI. This made me wonder whether collinearity could be an issue here; however, there was no correlation between age or BMI and any of the biochemical parameters (r<0.1).
- If I take a random subset of the initial dataset of the same size as the dataset without those taking supplements, I rarely get the warnings (the warnings appeared once across 10 different random sub-samples of the original dataset).
- This made me wonder if near-perfect separation might be causing the warnings; however, both the means of continuous variables and the counts from `table()` of the categorical variables across different subsets of the data show no difference compared to the subset of the data that has not supplement use.

The fact that I get the error consistently on the subset not taking the supplements but rarely on random subsets suggests the problem lies in the dataset subset and not the modelling. However, I cannot pinpoint the exact problem.